# Make a variable from a list item

Tags: variables, sass

I'm want to make a variable from a list item, but i can't find a method to paste a dollar sign a front of it. Beneath are the methods that i tried.

```
$hoi: yellow;
$test: hoi;

helpMe{
  background: $#{$test}; //error
  background: $$test; //error
  background: $nth($test, 1); //error
  background: unquote("$")#{$test}; //output: $hoi
  background: unquote("$")nth($test, 1); //output: $ hoi
};
```

Is there any method to paste a dollar sign before a variable and still get recognized as a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pure SASS, you can't declare variables with names taken from other variables.

You can only do that using a template to generate Sass code and then parse it.

Here's an example of how Compass does it for generating sprite variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16129685/901944

Bun i strongly advise against it. This is poor practice that leads to spaghetti code that's difficult to maintain. In most cases you can manage without that approach.

Answer (score 0):

> yes you can set  make a variable from a list item.
>
> for example:-

```
font: #{$font-size}/#{$line-height};
```

> and in your case:-

```
$hoi: yellow;
$test: hoi;

helpMe{
  background: #{$test};
};
```

Comment: You don't answer my question, i want to call $hoi through the variable $test